# C# Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'object[*,*]'

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a method that I'm attempting to update to accept multiple types of data so I used a generic.  I got it working with a couple different types, but one type that is being passed in is `object[,]`.  When I try to set the data to that type, I get the following error on conversion:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'T' to 'object[*,*]'`

The code is pretty simple with:

`object[,] data = (T)(object[,])element;`

Any ideas?

Comment: not a good practice but this will make it compile `object[,] data = (object[,])(object)element;`

Comment: If you're using generics, why do you have types hardcoded in the generic method? I feel like there's a bigger problem.

Comment: What is `T`? If you follow usual naming conventions, it may be a type parameter to a generic class/struct or a generic method. But there is no conversion from `T` to any array type. And what is the type of `element`? `T`?

Comment: Please include sufficient code for us to reproduce your issue: e.g. what is `element`, `T`, etc.

Comment: You need to explain better what the _intent_ of the code is. Can you show us more code and maybe an example of something that worked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're seeing is that since `T` neither derives from `object[,]` nor implements an [explicit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) [conversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85w54y0a.aspx), the code has literally no idea how to perform the conversion. This is because under the hood, conversions either box or unbox derived types, or call the conversion method in order to return the desired output type.

Since you're using a Generic, you can constrain the type using a [where](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) statement. As long as the constrained type (or a *more* derived type) defines and explicit conversion to (or derives from) `object[,]`, you'll be able to perform the conversion.